# Check if secured and change url

Tags: jquery, json, https

I have a piece of code which creates a menu depending on the link you click. The problem is that the menu doesn't work when you are on https://. So what I try to do is to check if the user is on https and the change the json request from http to https in the script.

I tried different things but with no luck. So what I have is:

```
function isSecure(){
  return location.protocol == 'https:';
}

$().ready(function(){
    $(document).on('mouseenter mouseleave', 'li.mega-menu', function(e){
    if(e.type == 'mouseenter'){      
      var catId = $(this).closest('[id]').attr('id');     
      var catHref = $(this).closest('[id]').children('a').attr('href');     
      menuWidget(catId, catHref);     
    }
  });  

function menuWidget(catId, catHref){   

  var url = catHref + 'page1.html'; // this needs to be https or http

  $.getJSON(url, function (json){     


    // .... etc etc  .... //

  });
}
```

Does anyone know how to use the isSecure function properly so that when you are on a https:// page the json requests a https link instead of http??

Comment: http://www.paulirish.com/2010/the-protocol-relative-url/

Comment: why you have mouseleave when not using it and putting extra if condition for mouseenter?

Comment: Have you reference any js lib from web?

Comment: @kostasch.: Yes offcourse

Comment: @BhushanKawadkar: Yes your right, changed it!

Comment: Check the url. You need `https://ajax.googleapis.com/` for example.